# Create shareable annotations for HTML, XML, SVG files

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, annotations

I am looking for the best approach for creating annotations for the following using **JS/Angular/NodeJS**.

```
 1. Annotating HTML - (comments, drawings, highlighting, etc)
 2. Annotating XML - (comments, drawings, highlighting, etc)
 3. Annotating SVG - (comments, drawings, highlighting, etc)
```

The implementation can be done using relative elements like HTML elements for HTML annotations etc.

But the implementation has to have a best way of having

```
 1. a unique reference to a specific annotated object
 2. able to export annotated objects related data in any structure like JSON
 3. able to import exported data and append/create related annotations 
using the unique reference based on the X, Y positions
```

So that all annotations can be shared among users and users would be able to import annotations to the same valid document.

What are the best patterns, strategies, and things that I need to consider for the above requirement?
If any guidelines, libraries are existing please share the links.

But custom implementation is the most preferred way

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing comments, drawings, and highlights as you say, for HTML, XML, and SVG files, I would recommend using HTML5 Canvas. If it were just annotations and comments, I would say to use DOM elements and keep track of position, but adding drawings to the picture complicates it.

If this were me, and I were doing this for production purposes, I would have two types of editors. First off, I would have image annotations which would cover all images and SVG's, then I would have document annotations which would use editable HTML and JavaScript to keep track of user actions and annotations.

One thing you may want to look at is Dropbox Paper, a web application which has most of the features you listed for editing documents.